# Airflow SLA on DAG level

Tags: airflow

Do you know the solution how to implement SLA on DAG level? I mean, the SLA within the whole DAG needs to be marked as success. Adding SLA parameter to default_args does not help here, because despite the fact this is a global parameter, it is evaluated on task level.

```
# Default settings applied to all tasks
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email': 'noreply@astronomer.io',
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'sla': timedelta(seconds=30)
}
```

Let's take example where we have DAG consisting of 3 tasks and SLA set as 2 hours. Suppose that each task proceeds 1 hour - the SLA is met despite the fact that it takes 3 hours to proceed whole DAG.

Do you know any solution for this? As far as I know there is no default setting for this.

Comment: SLA doesn't work the best. There are plans to change it in AIP-57.

[Confluence](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-57+Refactor+SLA+Feature), 

[Github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/32816)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an Airflow SLA on dag level. There are proposals to improve the entire SLA featureset. Follow here:

- [AIP-57 Refactor SLA Feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-57+Refactor+SLA+Feature)
- [GitHub Issue #32816](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/32816)

Your best bet is to create a separate dag that runs every 5 minutes and checks if dags have finished based on some meta driven value.